# Enviar mensagem para WhatsAPP via sistema

Tags: php, java

Estava lendo a respeito da WhatsAPI no StackOverflow, porem pelo método que tem descrito em perguntas anteriores, ele parece não estar funcionando. Alguém conhece algum método para enviar mensagem para Whatsapp, via php ou java?

Comment: Seria muito bom utilizar o WhatsApp para estas coisas...

Answer (score 9):

A WhatsApp **não permite** tal coisa conforme esta escrito no https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/ se você tem uma suposta API para usar ela não é oficial e sendo assim a Whatsapp irá procurar bloquear todo tipo deste tipo de ação que eles puderem detectar (claro que é possível burlar, só que não há garantia de quanto tempo irá funcionar).

Se você usar estas APIs não oficiais é bem provável que você apenas consiga que o numero do seu chip seja bloqueado, o whatsapp tem um token de segurança interno que a cada atualização eles podem mudar, assim dificultando o acesso, outra coisa que pode ter feito a API para de funcionar foi o modo de envio e entrega de dados que agora é criptografado.

Resumindo, talvez nestas técnicas, metodos, APIs, venham a ter atualizações futuras e assim poderão voltar a funcionar, mas não é garantia de quanto tempo irá funcionar, usar estes tipos de ações poderá marcar o numero do chip como SPAM.

Veja que até o repositório foi removido:

- https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

E o proprietário deixou essa imagem:

[image: legal]

Aparentemente o autor do repositório recebeu várias "ameaças" legais (ao menos assim é como ele se refere).